# Unreadable Text in JSON

Tags: json, unicode

I've been working a bit with some files from Minecraft Dungeons, which were extracted using QuickBMS and made available here: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki:Minecraft_Dungeons_game_files
In the "data" folder, there are a bunch of json-files, which I believe contain a list of textures associated with any given stage of the game. There is, however, a problem. When opened, it reads like any json-file, it has a bunch of names and values, but some of the values are not human-readable, they instead show up as a string of seemingly unrelated characters. Here an example:

```
 "walkable-plane" : "eNpjYSEOMIMAOp+ZmQmND1fEjF2AiQldAJsWDEPRXUKkowkDAM/qA6o=",
```

Now, given that these are exclusively characters, and not error signs or something of the sorts, I'm assuming this is an encoding issue. Of course, I don't know for sure, Or I wouldn't be asking this in the first place, but the file as it appears in the text is UTF-8, and it obviously doesn't produce a usable result. So, if anyone knows what exactly this is, and how I could extract information from it, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: This is base64 and contains binary data.

Comment: Though, now that I've tried a bit, how exactly do I turn this into readable english? Neither Unicode or ASCII seem to be working.

Comment: _binary data_ means _a computer language_ (how exactly do you turn e.g.  `石头` or `石頭` from Chinese language into readable English?)

Comment: No, I know that, but the same way I can write 石头 as both 石头 and shitou, I can write the letter A as both A and 65 (Decimal). The problem now is, that instead of translating to shitou, 石头 translates to ž§æ. The binary data returns gibberish, but it is supposed to give me a group of filenames.

Comment: It's *not* readable.  This particular data once base64-decoded  is a binary blob of some kind, not filenames.  What leads you to believe otherwise?  If it were text, it wouldn't need to be base64-encoded in the first place.

Comment: Because of its function within the game. The file is used to pass texture information from the resource folder to the models. The second question I can't answer, which is why I posted here in the first place.

Comment: Hi, should you still care about it: the base 64 string seems to refer to textures by their hex id, which i've found stored in ANOTHER json file.

Comment: If you want me to be notified of a new comment use @Mark in your note.  It would be a rather odd hex id, but `base64.b64decode(s)` will give you the raw binary data.